# is_displayed() method returning true even if WebElement is not visible

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I'm working on a test which, at some point, records some datas displayed in a scrollable table:

```
<div class='table-body'>
   <div class='scroll-wrapper>
      <div class='row'>
         <button class='button' type='button'></button>
         <div class='inner-data></div>
      </div>
      <div class='row'>
         <button class='button' type='button'></button>
         <div class='inner-data></div>
      </div>
      <div class='row'>
         <button class='button' type='button'></button>
         <div class='inner-data></div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

The total number of line present in the table is displayed on the screen, allowing me to use a **while** loop in order to be sure to collect all the datas.
However, as you can see on the html code, **each row has a button i'm clicking for every row**. And here is my issue : at some point, my method `find_elements_by_css_selector(div.row)` finds a WebElement which **is not visible on the window**, and tries to click on its `<button>`.
Consequently, i get the following error:

```
ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element <button class="btn" type="button"> could not be scrolled into view
```

I tried using `is_displayed()` method and `is_enabled()` to check if the element is visible on the screen, unfortunately they are always returning **True**.

Do you guys have any solutions ?

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element <button class="btn type="button"> could not be scrolled into view
```

...implies that the desired element could not be scrolled into view and is not interactable.

If you observe the relevant HTML the `<button>` tags are:

```
<button class='button' type='button'></button>
```

which are within the parent `<div>` tag as follows:

```
<div class='row'>
```

You have targetted the `<div>` tag with your *Locator Strategy*:

```
find_elements_by_css_selector(div.row)
```

But the error `ElementNotInteractableException` is returned for some other element:

```
<button class="btn      type="button">
observe the ^^^class^^^ attribute value
```

Which is of coarse not your desired element. Hence you see the error.

---

### Solution

As a solution to target the `<button>` tags you need to dig deeper one step further inducing induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibility_of_all_elements_located()` and click each of the elements and you can use either of the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  for element in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "div.table-body > div.scroll-wrapper div.row > button.button[type='button']"))):
      WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of(element)).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  for element in WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='table-body']/div[@class='scroll-wrapper']//div[@class='row']/button[@class='button' and @type='button']"))):
      WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of(element)).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports:

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: sorry, it was a spelling error in the post ^^. In my actual project, there is no such error. I edited the post to correct that, sorry. But the problem still remains

Comment: @ZoulouDu94 Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for your answer @DebanjanB. Your solution works well:

```
try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS-SELECTOR, "button"))):
    element.click()
except TimeoutException:
    # The button is not clickable, I scroll down
```

However, i know that the button is not clickable (and not visible) only when it's in the DOM but not visible on my window. And even if your solution works, it's quite time consuming, considering that i've a timeout after 20s. I know that I can decrease the time parameter in the `WebDriverWait(driver, time)` solution, but I found another solution:

```
try:
    self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector('button').click() 
except ElementNotInteractableException:
    # The button is not clickable, I scroll down
```

Anyway, thanks for you help, and I hope this trick can help others ;)

Comment: That wasn't a comment but a canonical answer :)